# Default argument not passed in body request

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I got a request (used with kotlinx.serialization.Serializable):

```
@Serializable
data class Request(
    val a: String,
    val b: String,
    val c: String = "version"
)
```

Part of retrofit / API code where I use this:

```
@PUT(value = "path/to/endpoint")
suspend fun sendRequest(@Body request: Request): Response

override fun sendRequest(request: Request) =
    flow<Resource<Response, NetworkError>> {
        emit(Resource.Success(network.sendRequest(request)))
    }.catch {
        emit(Resource.Error(it.parseNetworkError()))
    }
```

The default parameter `val c: String = "version"` does not follow in the request.

However, if I pass it in while creating the `Request` it works. Or if I put a breakpoint inspecting it before the `Request` is sent.

So this works:

```
Request("test", "test", "version")
```

But not this:

```
Request("test", "test")
```

Is this the compiler being smart and omitting it or something? How can I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: I can't think of any reason it would behave like that. But I notice your third argument is marked Long even though it's a String. Maybe in the process of refactoring you caused it not to work in some other way? Try repeating your AB behavior comparison to verify it's really misbehaving like you think.

Comment: Ah yes, that was a typo when I simplified my example. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be by design. According to the [kotlinx.serialization documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#defaults-are-not-encoded-by-default)...

```
Default values are not encoded by default in JSON. 
This behavior is motivated by the fact that in most real-life 
scenarios such configuration reduces visual clutter, and saves the 
amount of data being serialized.
```

If you want to turn it on for a property, you can annotate it with `@EncodeDefault`

```
@Serializable
data class Request(
    val a: String,
    val b: String,
    @EncodeDefault val c: String = "version"
)
```